# how to create a comparator of key in a map where the value of the key is a string in java?

Tags: list, sorting, tree, key, swap

how to create a comparator of key in a map where the value of the key is a string in java?

because i want to swap values of the keys in the map?

is there a way to sort this numbers stored in a string variable?

TreeMap`<String,List<QBFElement>> qbfElementMap = new TreeMap<String, List<QBFElement>>();`

27525-1813, 
27525-3989, 
27525-4083, 
27525-4670,
27525-4911, 
27526-558,
27526-1303, 
27526-3641, 
27526-4102, 
27527-683,
27527-2411, 
27527-4342

this is the list of keys and the value for each of the key is a list.
now, how can i sort this key in ascending order by number.

ex. if i want to sort : 1,2,11,20,31,3,10
i want to have as output is : 1,2,3,10,11,20,31
but when i use the autosort of treemap the output goes : 1,10,11,2,20,3,31

how can i sort it in ascending order by numeric?

and the language is java :) thank you:)

Comment: You might want to change the question title to something more akin to "How do I change the sort mechanism of a TreeMap"

Comment: And don't post duplicates of your own question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613022/how-to-swap-key-in-map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the TreeMap, provide a Comparator that sorts in the way you are expecting.

```
Map<String,List<QBFElement>> qbfElementMap = 
    new TreeMap<String,List<QBFElement>>(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            // compare your strings in ways that you understand
            // presumably 11111-0000 sorts before 11111-0001
            // left as an exercise for the reader
        }
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            return this == o;
        }
    });
```

But read the documentation for Comparator, including the bit about implementing Serializable, as it's particularly noted when using the Comparator in serializable data structures, like TreeMap

Answer (score 0):

You may want to override the default comparator function for String with your own.

Since this could screw up the comparison of other Strings, I recommend defining a NumericString class that contains the String and implements Comparable and using that instead of String in your map.

Comment: No, you want to provide a Comparator to the TreeMap which is then used for sorting...